# Python: Drawing random floating point numbers excluding some interval

Tags: python, python-2.7, random

I want to draw say 10 floating point numbers between `0.` and `2*np.pi` that are not in the range `(np.radians(101),np.radians(298))`. The brute force method is

```
rand_ra=[]
while len(rand_ra) <= 10:
    x=np.random.uniform(0.,2*np.pi,100) #pick 100 or whatever number you want
    for y in x :
        if 0. <= y <= np.radians(101) and np.radians(298)<=y<= 2.*np.pi :
             rand_ra.append(y)

print rand_ra
```

But this is super slow, because the excluded region is so large. Is there any less time consuming method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As we're dealing with a circle this is identical to drawing numbers in just the range `[np.radians(298) - 2 * pi, np.radians(101)]`.

That is:

```
sample = np.random.uniform(np.radians(298) - 2 * np.pi, np.radians(101), 100)
```

Then, simply normalise those that are less than `0`

```
sample[sample < 0] += 2 * np.pi
```

Comment: @HuShu Aw, give him the points.  This was a clever answer, I upvoted it myself.

Comment: @pjs agreed! :)

Answer (score 4):

Pre-calculate the size of the excluded range, `size = np.radians(298) - np.radians(101)`.  Generate values `y` between `0.` and `2*np.pi - size`. If `y` is greater than `np.radians(101)`, add `size` to it.